# pongo2 RegisterFilter how to return a map or array?

Tags: go

I need register a global filter to return userinfo from session.
I resister a new filter.

```
pongo2.RegisterFilter("getSessions", getSession)

func getSession(in, param *pongo2.Value) (*pongo2.Value,*pongo2.Error) {
    uInfo := lib.Sess.Get("userInfo")
    if uInfo == nil {
        lib.Logs.Error("get userinfo err from session")
    } else {
    }

    return pongo2.AsValue(uInfo), nil
}
```

and in the html i use like this:

```
{{ "getsess" | getSessions}}
```

but it's not work, the result is empty. but if reutrn a string is work well . 
if i want to return a map or array . how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `return in.Slice(start, limit), nil`

For example, This is implementation of `limit` filter can be used in for-loop.

https://github.com/mattn/jedie/blob/0f3fb468befcb71b026f07b4158e121da8b6b0c5/helper.go#L120-L125

Comment: thank you for help me.  I think i make a mistake when i get  struct 's value .   i find a right  way to resolve this problem .define a variable to receive user data   {% set uinfo = "" | getSessions %}  and get username use {{uinfo.Username}}